# Why am I losing image quality on my site?

Tags: functions, images

I have scoured every post possible about this topic and NOTHING I have tried has worked. Can someone please help me with this? I have a photoblog and I love my images when I open them on my computer, but after I upload them they don't look sharp at all. I've tried plugins and editing functions.php. Please help.

Comment: I see this a lot and it usually has to do with Retina Images. This is probably not the best place to find a solution to your problem as overall people will just be guessing in the answer section ( which we discourage - please view [discouraged topics](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and better suited asked on the [WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/) or some social media WordPress groups, maybe a local Meet Up. Have you give this [WP Retina 2x](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-retina-2x/) a try?

Comment: So, you have tried `add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){ return 100; });` and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained what kind of code changes you did in functions.php but the code you should put in your functions.php is

```
function jpeg_quality_controller( $quality, $context ) {
    return 100;
}
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'jpeg_quality_controller', 10, 2 );
```

> But this solution will not make any changes to already uploaded image files. Delete already uploaded images and try to re-upload them.

If you already did the above and still find your uploaded images are not as sharp as original, then it may have something to do with WordPress auto resizing. By default, WordPress resize your uploaded images in three different sizes Large, Medium and Thumbnail size. You can stop making these image resizing by adding the following code in your functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'remove_default_image_sizes');

function remove_default_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size('thumbnail');
    remove_image_size('medium');
    remove_image_size('medium_large');
    remove_image_size('large');
}
```

Now you are left with only the original size of images you upload.

> Again remember this solution will not make any changes to already uploaded image files. Delete already uploaded images and try to re-upload them.